# Почему PyScript зависает при добавлении в py-env стандартного модуля json

Tags: python, html, pyscript

Работаю с скриптом PyScript внутри HTML

Проблема в том, что если пытаюсь сам добавить модуль json в пример данный [в статье по ссылке](https://habr.com/ru/company/skillfactory/blog/669814/), то зависает загрузка страницы

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
        <py-env>
        - numpy
        - matplotlib
        # - json  -почему не работает с станд-тным модулем для работы с json, верхние два свободно
        </py-env>

      <py-script>

        s = 'test'
        print(s)

      </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

В py-env нужно добавлять только сторонние модули, стандартный модуль json добавлять не нужно, он и так будет доступен. Пример работы с ним:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <py-script>
        import json
        s = dict(some_data="test")

        output = Element("output")
        output.element.innerText = json.dumps(s)
      </py-script>

      <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```