# Бесконечная загрузка pyscript

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyscript

Я пробую создать сайт на pyscript первый раз(мне нужно для проекта).
При запуске начинается бесконечная загрузка

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>PyScript App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css"/>
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<py-config>
packages = ["amzqr"]
</py-config>
<py-script>
from amzqr import amzqr
import os


version, level, qr_name = amzqr.run(
    words = "https://pyscript.net",
    version=10,
    level='H',
    picture=None,
    colorized=True,
    contrast=1.0,
    brightness=1.0,
    save_name=None,
    save_dir=os.getcwd()
)
</py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Похоже, что по какой-то причине amzqr не хочет устанавливаться (в консоли пишет, что модуль не найден). Если подключать через `<py-env>`, как в этом вопросе, то вроде бы запускается: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1422191/1365, хотя py-env сейчас даже в документации нет

Comment: Спасибо сработало